# Solve an exponential equation in integers

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

> Find two integers x and y such that $x^y +y^x = 94032$.

I have used

```
Solve[x^y + y^x == 94032, {x, y}, Integers]
Reduce[x^y + y^x == 94032, {x, y}, Integers]
FindInstance[x^y + y^x == 94032, {x, y}, Integers]
```

But I can not find the integers that are the solution

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Is it possible there are no integer solutions? ContourPlot[x^y + y^x == 94032, {x, 5.1, 6.2}, {y, 5.8, 6.9}]

Comment: Also, transcendental Diophantine equations are hard.

Comment: $x=1,y=94031$ is solution.

Comment: There are at least two solutions : x^y + y^x /. {x -> 94031, y -> 1}
x^y + y^x /. {x -> 1, y -> 94031} gives 94032

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki these are the only two solutions in the integer domain

Comment: Wow Thanks. **Why Mathematica does not find such trivial solutions?**

Comment: Frequently, adding bounds to variables helps Mathematica find solutions. In your case, including x>0 and y>0 in Solve does not help, but including 10>x>0 does. The tighter the bound, the quicker the solution, suggesting Mathematica is using a brute-force algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

There is always a trivial solution: $x=n-1,y=1$.

You can use brute force to find non trivial solutions.

**Method 1.** Calculate $x^y+y^x$ for all pairs $x < \sqrt{n}$ and $y < \sqrt{n}$. Since we are not interested in trivial solutions, we don't need to check $x > \sqrt{n}$. Then check if we have $n$ in the result list.

```
findNonTrivialPairs[n_]:=Select[{#1, #2, #1^#2 + #2^#1} & @@@ Tuples[#, 2] &@
    Range[Ceiling@Sqrt[n]], #[[3]] == n &];
findNonTrivialPairs[100]
(* {{2, 6, 100}, {6, 2, 100}} *)

AbsoluteTiming@findNonTrivialPairs[94032]    
(* {0.545318, {}}  <- no non-trivial solutions *)
```

**Method 2.**

We will look for pairs where $y > x$, so iterations over y start with $x$

```
f[{x_, y_, z_}] := {x, y + 1, x^(y + 1) + (y + 1)^x};    
g[x_, n_] := NestWhile[f, {x, x, 0}, #[[3]] < n &];     
findPairs[n_] :=Select[Map[g[#, n] &,Range[n/2]], #[[1]]^#[[2]] + #[[2]]^#[[1]] == n &];

findPairs[100]

(* {{1, 99, 100}, {2, 6, 100}} it has non-trivial solutions *)
```

Let's find non-trivial solutions for $100<n<200$

```
Rest /@ Select[findPairs /@ Range[100, 1000], Length[#] > 1 &]
(* {{{2, 6, 100}}, {{3, 4, 145}}, {{2, 7, 177}}, {{2, 8, 320}}, {{3, 5, 
   368}}, {{2, 9, 593}}, {{3, 6, 945}}} *)
```

For your particular $n=94032$  it seems to have no non-trivial solution (and it takes some time to calculate it):

```
AbsoluteTiming@findPairs[94032]
(* {108.22, {{1, 94031, 94032}}} *)
```

> **Update**: We don't need to iterate up to `n/2` we can iterate up to `l`, where `l^l=n`

It will significantly increase performance.

```
limit[n_] := Ceiling[x /. FindRoot[x^x == n, {x, 1}]];
findPairs2[n_] := 
  Select[Map[g[#, n] &,Range[limit[n]]], #[[1]]^#[[2]] + #[[2]]^#[[1]] == n &];

AbsoluteTiming@findPairs2[94032]
(* {0.401372, {{1, 94031, 94032}}} *)
```

Comment: Great analysis, many ways I did not know, thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

you can actually very simply show there are only the trivial solutions:

1) note it is sufficient to consider `x<=y` , so `2 x^x <= 94032` or `x<=6`.

Then:

```
 Table[ {x, y /. FindRoot[ x^y + y^x == 94032 , {y, x}]}, {x, 6}]
```

> {{1, 94031.}, {2, 16.5167}, {3, 10.4125}, {4, 8.22445}, {5, 
>     6.99343}, {6, 6.00551}}

Comment: thanks, Very effective and concise